# Rebasing and Pull request

Tags: git, github

I am working on open source plugin and I have made all the changes which were necessary. Currently, I am in master branch of my version of work. I want to rebase updates from the original work and then send a pull request. Could anyone please help what steps do I need to take for rebasing and then for pull request? Thanks

Comment: things appart, that's better to create a pull request from another branch than the 'master' one. Create one with a good name before creating the pull request.

Comment: thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a simple rebase as follows:

```
git fetch upstream # or whatever your remote is
git rebase upstream/master
```

This might introduce conflicts you need to fix before pushing obviously.

You can now submit your pull request. I'd suggest doing it from a named branch rather than master. You can do this when pushing to Github (or any remote) as follows:

```
git push origin master:my_awesome_feature
```

And it will create a branch on the remote named `my_awesome_feature`

If you want to squash your commits (interactive rebase), you'll still need to do the above steps, but then look here: [Squash my last X commits together using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5189560/1554635)